# Transform JSON file to add keys to array values

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am using Apache NiFi and receive from an embedded micro over a TCP/IP socket a JSON file of the form:

{
  "id": 123456,
  "ip": "192.168.1.1",
  "t": -12.9,
  "T": -23.8,
  "variables": [
    "user1",
    0,
    -12.97,
    23.87
  ]
}

and would like to transform it such that the keys of the variables are added as they are known to me as follows:

{
  "id": 123456,
  "ip": "192.168.1.1",
  "t": -12.9,
  "T": -23.8,
  "variables": [
    "username" : "user1",
    "valid" : 0,
    "temperature 1" : -12.97,
    "temperature 2" : 23.87
  ]
}

and then to be able to access a key value pair such as variables.username.

I have tried using JoltTransformJSON but don't know how to write the spec correctly if it can do it!!  I have written the following jolt spec:

[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "ip": "ip",
      "t": "t",
      "T": "T",
      "variables": {
        "username": "",
        "valid": "",
        "temperature 1": "",
        "temperature 2": ""
      }
    }
  }
]

I also have tried using UpdateRecord with Record Reader/Writer but passing the correct schema causes an error on the first variable as it can't match "user1" with a key from the initial JSON.

Comment: check JoltTransformJson processor

Comment: Have tried using JoltTransformJson processor but can't managed to get it working.  Even tried using http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/.
I also have tried using UpdateRecord with Record Reader/Writer but passing the correct schema causes an error on the first variable

Comment: please edit your question and provide your jolt transformation then maybe somebody will help you with it. also add a `jolt` tag/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to work out the Jolt Spec as follows:

[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "ip": "ip",
      "t": "t",
      "T": "T",
      "variables": {
        "0": "username",
        "1": "valid",
        "2": "temperature 1",
        "3": "temperature 2"
      }
    }
  }
]

Thank you daggett for your contribution.